# Как вариант

Tags: как, пунктуация

Извиняюсь, если вопрос уже сто раз задавался.
Нужна ли запятая, если "как вариант" стоит в конце предложения? В значении "можно сделать так, но необязательно".
Напр. "Можно объединить эти два предложения, как вариант".

Answer (score 1):

Обособление оборота "как вариант" является факультативным и определяется  по структуре предложения и позицией оборота в нем. Оборот не обособляется, если входит в основное сообщение в нераспространенном предложении. В остальных случаях оборот имеет имеет значение добавочного сообщения и обособляется.

ПРИМЕРЫ

1) Оборот не обособляется:  Это просто как вариант. Как вариант подходит. Жить "на пособие" я не рассматриваю как вариант.

2) Оборот обособляется (иногда с помощью тире):

Как вариант, можно предложить зафиксировать существующий уровень финансирования. Это я только так, как вариант (пояснение). И как вариант, было предложено переделывать машины, переставляя руль с одной стороны на другую. Как вариант, можно предложить зафиксировать существующий уровень финансирования. Как вариант ― нужен кредит.

РЕШЕНИЕ

1) В данном случае это добавочное сообщение, которое желательно обособить: "Можно объединить эти два предложения, как вариант". Или: "Можно объединить эти два предложения - как вариант".

В то же время позиция оборота не очень подходит для обособления, поэтому лучше перестроить предложение: "Можно, как вариант, объединить эти два предложения". "Как вариант, можно объединить эти два предложения".

Answer (score -1):

Здесь напрашивается "как" в значении "в качестве", поэтому  не придает двусмысленности фраза: "Можно объединить эти два предложения как вариант" (в качестве варианта).